# Random sampling

Tags: r, random

I would like to know how to implement a way to get a random sub-sample within a larger sample in R using a large collection of true random numbers (obtained using a quantum generator) those are integers which can have multiple occurrences.

__

Edit: Solution.

Since I needed a remise and my generated numbers in a float64 were finally unique (due to the high precision), I have used the following solution :

1) generate as many numbers as length(data)

2)

```
temp<-cbind(data,randomnb)
randomizeddata<-res[order(res[,2])]
```

3) split the dataset

Comment: I wonder if you mean that R's internal random number generator isn't up to your standards, and so using it to 'randomly' select a subset of your fancily generated pseudo-random numbers defeats their purpose. So maybe you mean you want to use your pre-generated random #'s to generate a subset of itself? Or am I being too cute about this? ;)

Comment: @delphine: it would be interesting to know why pseudorandom numbers aren't okay in this case.  (R uses Mersenne Twister, which is good enough for most purposes; there are other bleeding edge algorithms available via the `randtoolbox` package.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For true random numbers, use `randomNumbers` from the `random` package.

```
r <- randomNumbers(number_of_samples, max = nrow(your_data), col = 1)
your_data[r, ]
```

Comment: Cool! So it uses the website random.org, which uses atmospheric noise to generate the numbers. Good to know!

Comment: Thank you, this solution is a good one. However, I will use another solution since I have randoms numbers with much better quality (the generator obtain better results in the DieHard test) and my generated numbers were finally unique.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `v` is your data and `r` are the true random numbers (scaled so that they range from `0` to `1`):

```
> v <- runif(100)
> r <- runif(10) # using psedo-random numbers for demo purposes
> v[r * length(v) + 1]
```

This selects ten random elements from `v` (with replacement).

Comment: Since indices in R are 1-based, you need to add one: `v[r * length(v) + 1]`

Comment: Thank you. I have used another method since my random numbers were unique when generating float64 reals from [0,1].

Answer (score 0):

What about [sample](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sample.html) function ?

e.g.

```
set.seed(3) # just to get the same result
x <- 1:10
sample(x,10)
# print: 2  8  4  3  9  6  1  5 10  7
```

Comment: This is the best option if pseudorandom numbers are allowed.

Comment: @Richie: yes, but you can also use it to create a subset from another vector of numbers, or to shuffle them. It really depends on what actually the OP needs. He seems to have a vector of "truly-random" generated elements, so probably sample() is even useless, because if they're truly random... why don't take just a portion of it ? :)